# Invalid syntax when importing numpy or tensorflow in tensorflow environment

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, import, anaconda

These are my config:
Python 3.9.13
conda 4.13.0
tensorflow 2.6.0
numpy 1.23.1

The first time I tried to install the tensorflow package in the base environment using anaconda navigator, it ran for about 4 to 5 hours before it stopped and failed to install due to multiple conflicts and incompatibilities (couple of hundreds lines of error log). My hdd space dropped by about 5 GB during that time and did not return even though the installation failed.

I then installed the tensorflow-gpu package using anaconda navigator in a newly created environment called 'tensorflow'.

There were no errors during installation this time and my hdd space dropped by another 5GB. But when I tried to import tensorflow or numpy in the new environment it gave this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Sherline's
> PC.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
> line 3552, in run_code
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> File "C:\Users\Sherline's
> PC\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1922024\394405890.py", line 1, in
> <cell line: 1>
> import numpy
>
> File "C:\Users\Sherline's
> PC.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py", line
> 124, in 
> from numpy.**config** import show as show_config
>
> File "C:\Users\Sherline's
> PC.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy_*config*_.py", line
> 14
> blas_info={'libraries': ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas'], 'library_dirs': ['C:/Users/Sherline's
> PC/.conda/envs/tensorflow\Library\lib'], 'include_dirs':
> ['C:/Users/Sherline's PC/.conda/envs/tensorflow\Library\include'],
> 'language': 'f77', 'define_macros': [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]}
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

location of the error where the carrot is pointing
[image: location of the error where the carrot is pointing]

In case you can't see where the carrot ^ is pointing, it is pointing at the lowercase 's' in "Sherline's PC". Is that what's causing the invalid syntax error? Is there a workaround? Why don't I get the error when I import numpy in the base environment?

Thanks in advance!
p.s. How do I get my initial 5GB of HDD space back?

Comment: likely the single quote is causing the issue

Comment: You're right! I added the escape \ in front and I can import them now! Thanks David!

Comment: Glad that you could manage to use my hint!